# Formatting list.sort function in Python

Tags: python, formatting

I have a function in which the user enters 3 numbers and it returns the average of those 3 numbers as well as a second line ordering them in increasing order.

It currently looks like the below:

```
num1 = input('Enter your first number: ')
num2 = input('Enter your second number: ')
num3 = input('Enter your third number: ')
sum = float(num1) + float(num2) + float(num3)
avg = round(sum/3, 2)
print('The average is ' + str(avg))
list = [num1, num2, num3]
list.sort()
print('The numbers in order are {}'.format(list))
```

this returns:

```
Enter your first number: 1
Enter your second number: 2
Enter your third number: 3
The average is 2.0
The numbers in order are ['1', '2', '3']
```

However I am having I want it to return the last line in the following format instead:

```
The numbers in order are 1, 2, 3
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on functions to be able to format the line to how I need?

Comment: Try `.format(','.join(list))` instead of `.format(list)`

Comment: I would strongly recommend not naming a list "list", you're shadowing the built-in.

Answer (score 1):

```
print('The numbers in order are {}'.format(', '.join(list)))
```

That said, you should not be shadowing the `list` builtin and should be using a different name for your variable.

Comment: Thankyou - this worked well. Appreciate the feedback, I've changed the variable from list

Answer (score 0):

Try this using Python f-Strings:

```
print(f'The numbers in order are {", ".join(list)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list.sort()
list= str(list)[1:-1] 
print('The numbers in order are {}'.format(list))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.